# Update Python 2 and 3 with Conda

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am running Ubuntu and have installed Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 (before I knew about environments). I'd like to update both versions using, say:

```
conda update anaconda 

# or
conda update --all
```

However, when I run this command, it only updates Anaconda2. I've tried using:

```
conda3 update anaconda

# and
conda3 update --all
```

For now, I'd like to keep the configuration the same, i.e., not uninstall Anaconda 2 or 3 and create an environment within the one I keep.

Comment: Why not just make an alias ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , I'm not sure how to go about that. I'm relatively new to the command line/linux.

Comment: You will need to append anaconda 3 to the front of your path variable.  That will direct the `conda` call to your anaconda 3 directory instead of anaconda 2.

Comment: @James, will I not have the same issue: conda will only update 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments: I've decided it's just easier to uninstall Anaconda3 and create an environment:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

To activate I use:

```
source activate py35

# to deactivate
source deactivate
```